# Reporting information of other agents

Tags: netlogo

Question. I have agents moving in the environment. I would like them to record at the beginning and at the end of a step: 
in a radius of one patch how many other agents (neighbors) there are (minus themselves) and their characteristics. They should put this in a list or so that gets added.
Is this possible? I'm struggling.

Edit 1: changed tick to step and added (neighbors)

Comment: I don't think you mean to say beginning and end of a tick, but instead, step. Also, in-radius of one patch? do you mean the neighbors?

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, I meant step. Yes, the neighbors. I edited it now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a breed-variable that keeps this information.

You can just append (using lput) the count the turtles in the radius (using the in-radius)

```
turtles-own [beginning-step end-step]

to go 
   ask turtles [set beginning-step lput (count other (turtles in-radius 1)) beginning-step]
   ask turtles [ move]
   ask turtles [set end-step lput (count other (turtles in-radius 1)) end-step]
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I can probably also use this to record for example their characteristics?